# When the radiation spectrum of two bodies will be undistinguishable?

Tags: thermal-radiation

While reading my book I came a cross the question that .

Suppose there is solid sphere of radius $r$ inside a spherical shell of radius $R$.
If a heating source is connected to the inner solid sphere the spectrum of both bodies will be non distinguishable. ($r<R$)

But I am thinking that as the inner solid is sphere receives heat energy from the source its temperature would rise so it would emit radiation to the spherical shell. This leads to increase in temperature of this spherical shell. After some amount of time the heat flow would be continuous and steady state would be reached. And each of them gets a unique temperature .So their radiation spectrum will be distinguishable.

But in solution its given that **undistinguishable spectrum**.

[image: The given image is]